# Create a JSON type nested dictionary from a list in Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I wish to create a JSON type nested dictionary from a list of lists. The lists contained a full directory path, but I broke them into their individual components as I thought it would make the creation of the nested dictionaries easier.

An example list:

```
["root", "dir1", "file.txt"]
```

The expected result:

```
{
    "type": "directory",
    "name": "root",
    "children": [
        {
            "type": "directory",
            "name": "dir1",
            "children": [
                {
                    "type": "file",
                    "name": "file.txt",
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tried using a recursive method but couldn't quite get there (new to recursive methods and my head continually spun out). Also tried an iterative method from an idea I found here (stack overflow) which inverted the list and build the dict backwards, which I kind of got to work, but was unable to solve one of the solution requirements, which is that the code can deal with duplication in parts of the directory paths as it iterates over the list of lists.
For example following on from the last example, the next inputted list is this:-

```
["root", "dir1", "dir2", "file2.txt"]
```

and it need to build onto the JSON dictionary to produce this:-

```
{
    "type": "directory",
    "name": "root",
    "children": [
        {
            "type": "directory",
            "name": "dir1",
            "children": [
                {
                    "type": "file",
                    "name": "file.txt",
                }
                {
                    "type": "directory",
                    "name": "dir2",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "type": "file",
                            "name": "file2.txt"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and so on with an unknown number of lists containing directory paths.
Thanks.

Comment: how do you know what is a file and what's a directory?

Comment: Are they all absolute paths (i.e. start at `root`)?

Comment: What is a "folder" and what is a "file" is decided by their position in the list. The last value in the list is always a file and all preceding strings relate to folders. They are all absolute paths, starting from root.

Comment: Thanks for the solutions, I'll try them soon and get back with the outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recursive solution with [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) is as follows (assuming all paths are absolute paths). The idea is to group paths by the first element in the path list. This groups similar directory roots together, allowing us to call the function recursively on that group.

Also note that file names cannot be duplicated in a directory, so all files will be grouped as single element lists by `groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

def build_dict(paths):
    if len(paths) == 1 and len(paths[0]) == 1:
        return {"type": "file", "name": paths[0][0]}
    dirname = paths[0][0]
    d = {"type": "directory", "name": dirname, "children": []}
    for k, g in groupby(sorted([p[1:] for p in paths], key=itemgetter(0)),
                        key=itemgetter(0)):
        d["children"].append(build_dict(list(g)))
    return d    

paths = [["root", "dir1", "file.txt"], ["root", "dir1", "dir2", "file2.txt"]]
print(build_dict(paths))
```

**Output**

```
{
  "type": "directory",
  "name": "root",
  "children": [
    {
      "type": "directory",
      "name": "dir1",
      "children": [
        {
          "type": "directory",
          "name": "dir2",
          "children": [
            {
              "type": "file",
              "name": "file2.txt"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "file",
          "name": "file.txt"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a naive recursive solution that simply walks through the tree structure, adding children as necessary, until the last element of `path` is reached (assumed to be a file).

```
import json


def path_to_json(path, root):
    if path:
        curr = path.pop(0)

        if not root:
            root["type"] = "file"
            root["name"] = curr

            if path:
                root["children"] = [{}]
                root["type"] = "directory"
                path_to_json(path, root["children"][0])
        elif path:
            try:
                i = [x["name"] for x in root["children"]].index(path[0])
                path_to_json(path, root["children"][i])
            except ValueError:        
                root["children"].append({})
                path_to_json(path, root["children"][-1])

    return root


if __name__ == "__main__":
    paths = [["root", "dir1", "file.txt"], 
             ["root", "dir1", "dir2", "file2.txt"]]
    result = {}
    print(json.dumps([path_to_json(x, result) for x in paths][0], indent=4))
```

Output:

```
{
    "type": "directory",
    "name": "root",
    "children": [
        {
            "type": "directory",
            "name": "dir1",
            "children": [
                {
                    "type": "file",
                    "name": "file.txt"
                },
                {
                    "type": "directory",
                    "name": "dir2",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "type": "file",
                            "name": "file2.txt"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

[Try it!](https://repl.it/repls/FaroffLinearProjects)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion ggorlen. It provides the expected output, but can you please tell me why the *path_to_json* method retains memory of the dictionary it created after the methed has returned back into *main* (following the *return root*). It seems to be acting like a generator, but I can't find anything in the code that defines it that way.

Comment: That's actually poor design on my part. Each call after the first uses the same `{}` as in the original default parameter. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Given not much detail has been provided, here is a solution that uses a reference to enter each nested `dict`

```
In [537]: structure = ["root", "dir1", "dir2", "file2.txt"]

In [538]: d = {}

# Create a reference to the current dict
In [541]: curr = d

In [542]: for i, s in enumerate(structure):
     ...:     curr['name'] = s
     ...:     if i != len(structure) - 1:
     ...:         curr['type'] = 'directory'
     ...:         curr['children'] = {}
     ...:         curr = curr['children']          # New reference is the child dict
     ...:     else:
     ...:         curr['type'] = 'file'
     ...:

In [544]: from pprint import pprint

In [545]: pprint(d)
{'children': {'children': {'children': {'name': 'file2.txt', 'type': 'file'},
                           'name': 'dir2',
                           'type': 'directory'},
              'name': 'dir1',
              'type': 'directory'},
 'name': 'root',
 'type': 'directory'}
```

I don't know if this will work for all of your questions as the spec isn't very detailed